# Is there a name for points that are elements of every non-empty closed subset of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

A *generic point* of a topological space $X$ is a point of $X$ that is an element of every non-empty open subset of $X$.

Is there a name for points that are elements of every non-empty closed subset of a topological space (or equivalently that are elements of no other open subset other than $X$ itself)?

Comment: Do you have any examples in mind? Note that there are no such points if $X$ has at least two closed points...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Preorders equipped with the topology of upper sets (every upper set is open) have a maximum if and only if they have a generic point (and then both coincide) and a minimum if and only if they have a …

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Spectra of local rings have unique closed points and, topologically, they are …

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I don’t think he has. If a space has two distinct closed points, no point can be element of both of their respective, closed singletons.

Comment: I dk of a name but the set of generic points sounds good. Its complement is the union of all proper open subsets, and if the space is not empty, this complement is the largest open proper subset.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I’m not sure I follow. What do you mean by “the set of generic points sounds good”?

Comment: At worst you can go with “co-generic”.